# Share data between app.js and html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

Using Node.js and Express, my first route determines the client's language :

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = module.exports = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
    ent = require('ent'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    request = require('request');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  var ip = req.ip;
  request('http://freegeoip.net/json/' + ip, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
        var code = data.country_code.toLowerCase();
    }
  });
  res.render('index.ejs');
});
```

Then I need to pass `code` to index.ejs to display the appropriate language.

Some people suggest to use Angular to share a scope, but Angular isn't defined in my app, only in index.ejs. I'm not sure if I should add it to app.js or not.

Others suggest to use `module.exports` on the app but `require` doesn't work on the front end either.

What is a good way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Call `res.render` inside the callback after you've called `http://freegeoip.net`, and pass any data needed to render the view as an object parameter, to `res.render`, i.e.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var ip = req.ip;
    request('http://freegeoip.net/json/' + ip, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(body);
            var code = data.country_code.toLowerCase();
            res.render('index.ejs', {
                code: code
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: then how to access it from index.ejs ?

Comment: you can include it using the `<%=` operator i.e., `<%= code %>` anywhere in ejs

Comment: thanks.. I realised it didn't work because I was testing locally and 127.0.0.1 doesn't give a location.. silly me !